# CSS not applying on slideshow after Ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax, slideshow

I am trying to dynamically load data when reaching the bottom of a page (using the onScroll event handler). 
The data I want to load are, mostly, slideshows and, behind them, (each one inside a different div), an iframe with an embedded vimeo.

The problem is that when I first access the page the slideshows appear in the right position; images are stacked, on hover slideshows pausing and resuming just like expected, so does the iframe behind them. But when I hit the bottom of the page, new slideshows appear but the slideshow won't work; the images are not stacked. Looks like they lose the CSS. They don't appear in the right place.

Some code I find relevant.

This is the CSS for the slideshow:

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->
.slides{
    z-index:10;
}
.slides.active{
    visibility:visible;
}
.imagen {
    position:relative;
    height:393px;
    width:700px;
    margin-left:10px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

This is the JavaScript for the slideshow:

```
     <!-- language: lang-js-->

    $('.slides').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
         speed:   1500,
        timeout: 70,
    }).cycle('pause');


    $('.imagen').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
        }, function(){
         $(this).find('.slides').removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
        });
```

This is the JavaScript to load more content on the onScroll event handler:

```
      <!-- language: lang-js-->
     var loaded=false;
        $(window).scroll(function(){  
var WindowHeight = $(window).height(); 
            if($(window).scrollTop() +1 >= $(document).height() - WindowHeight){ 

                if ( !loaded ) {
                $("#loader").html("<img src='recursos/imagenes/loading_icon.gif' alt='loading'/>"); 
                var LastDiv = $(".videobox:last"); 
                var LastId  = $(".videobox:last").attr("id");
                var ValueToPass = "lastid="+LastId; /* create a variable that containing the url parameters which want to post to getdata.php file */loaded=true;}
                $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: "data.php",
                data: ValueToPass,
                cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#loader").html("");
                        LastDiv.after(html); 
                        loaded=false;}
                });
            }
        });
```

I will take all critics/feedbacks, as possible, on this code, even if it means starting all over.

If needed, I can post the html or images or give more explanations on what should be the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you call this line

```
// Cycle plugin
$('.slides').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed:   1500,
    timeout: 70,
}).cycle('pause');
```

only after the page has loaded once. So the plugin works only for the elements that have been there at the beginning. You should also activate the plugin to the new slides which are loaded via ajax:

```
$.ajax({ /* post the values using AJAX */
    type: "POST",
    url: "data.php",
    data: ValueToPass,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $("#loader").html("");
        LastDiv.after(html); /* get the out put of the getdata.php file and append it after the last div using after(), for each scroll this function will execute and display the results */
        loaded=false;
        // Assign cycle plugin again for the new elements.
        $('.slides').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed:   1500,
            timeout: 70,
        }).cycle('pause');
    }
});
```

This code makes also the new loaded content slideable.

Comment: Thank you very much, ive implemented what you suggested and also added the hover so i got it to work perfectly and that also solved the position issues. that brought a question to myself, will i always have to call everything twice? one time for the content loaded on page load and one time for the content loaded via ajax? thanks again for the precise answer.